Proof that $\|F_B\|\leq\|F\|$.
Background Information
Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $p$ satisfy $1\leq p<+\infty$. Let $F$ be an arbitrary element of $(L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu))^*$, so $F$ is a continuous linear functional on $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.
Suppose that $B$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}$. Let $\mathscr{A}_B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $B$ consisting of those subsets of $B$ that belong to $\mathscr{A}$. Let $\mu_B$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to $\mathscr{A}_B$. If $f$ is a real- or complex-valued function on $B$, then we will denote by $f'$ the function on $X$ that agrees with $f$ on $B$ and vanishes outside $B$. The formula $F_B(\langle f\rangle)=F(\langle f'\rangle)$ defines a linear functional $F_B$ on $L^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$. Show that this functional satisfies $\|F_B\|\leq\|F\|$.

What I Have Tried So Far
Let $\langle f\rangle\in L^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$, so that $f\in\mathscr{L}^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$, which implies $|f|^p$ is integrable (on $(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$), that is $\int|f|^pd\mu_B<+\infty$. But $\int|f|^pd\mu_B=\int|f'|^pd\mu$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
    F_B(\langle f\rangle) &= F(\langle f'\rangle)\\
    &\leq \|F\|\cdot\|\langle f'\rangle\|_p\\
    &= \|F\|\cdot\|f'\|_p\\
    &= \|F\|\cdot\left(\int|f'|^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
    &= \|F\|\cdot\left(\int|f|^pd\mu_B\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
    &= \|F\|\cdot\|f\|_{p,B}\\
    &= \|F\|\cdot\|\langle f\rangle\|_{p,B},
\end{align*}
where $\|\cdot\|_{p,B}$ is the norm defined on $\mathscr{L}^p(B,\mathscr{A}_b,\mu_B)$ or on $L^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$. Thus $\|F\|$ is a bound for the linear operator $F_B$. So $\|F_B\|$ as the infimum of the set of bounds for must be less than or equal to $\|F\|$.

My Question

I am not sure whether it is legit to say $\int|f|^pd\mu_B=\int|f'|^pd\mu$, because they are defined on different spaces.

Moreover, I am not sure whether it is legit to define a $\|\cdot\|_{p,B}$ and then use it as how I did in the equations.


I would really appreciate it if someone would help me with these questions!

For your second question: There is no need to "define" $||\cdot||_{p,B}$. It is just  the norm from $L^p(B,\mathscr{A}B,\mu_B)$ given by $||\langle f\rangle||{p,B}^p=\int |f |^p , d\mu_B$.

@Föölücks The reason I feel I might need to "define" the norm $|\cdot|_{p,B}$  on $L^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$ (or seminorm on $\mathscr{L}^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$) is because $|\cdot|_p$ is defined to be the norm on $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ (or seminorm on $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$). So the notations $|f|_p$ and $|\langle f\rangle|_p$ would not make any sense as $f$ is a function defined on $B$ but not on $X$.


Intuitivly, it should be clear that: $$\int|f|^p\,d\mu_B=\int|f'|^p\,d\mu.$$
For a rigorous derivation we apply the standard measure theoretic argument  of using approximation by simple functions. So approximate $|f|^p$ by a monotonic increasing sequence of simple functions $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n=|f|^p.$  Say  $g_n:B\to [0,\infty]$ with $g_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{m_n}a_{n,j}\mathbf{1}_{B_{n,j}}(x)$, where $a_{n,j}>0$ and $B_{n,j}\in\mathscr{A}_B$.
Then since the $g_n$ are $\mathscr{A}_B$ measurable, they are also $\mathscr{A}$ measurable. Clearly $g_n':X\to [0,\infty]$ given by $g'_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{m_n}a_{n,j}\mathbf{1}_{B_{n,j}}(x)$  also approximates $|f'|^p$. So applying the monoton convergence theorem and using $\mu|_B=\mu_B$, we obtain:
$$\begin{align*} \int|f|^p\,d\mu_B&=\int \lim_{n\to\infty}g_n\,d\mu_B=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int g_n\,d\mu_B=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{m_n}a_{n,j}\cdot\mu_B(B_{n,j})\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{m_n}a_{n,j}\cdot\mu(B_{n,j})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int g'_n\,d\mu=\int \lim_{n\to\infty}g'_n\,d\mu=\int |f'|^pd\mu.
\end{align*}$$

If you have a $L^p$ space you also automatically get its norm. As pointed out in the comments you can  not write  $\|f\|_p$, because $f:B\to \mathbb{C}$ is not in the domain of $\|\cdot\|_p$. But $f$ is in the domain of the norm of $L^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$. So you can simply say, you denote the norm on $L^p(B,\mathscr{A}_B,\mu_B)$ by $\|\cdot\|_{B,p}$.


Hope this helps :)
